# Remove directive for a particular element AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, jquery-ui

I have implemented a drag and drop feature in AngularJS. Once I drop an item "i" onto bin "b", I want that "i" should become non-draggable and "b" should become non-droppable.

App.js snippet:

```
app.directive('draggable', function () {
    return function (scope, element) {
        var el = element[0];
        el.draggable = true;
        el.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
            e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);
            this.classList.add('drag');
            return false;
        }, false);
        el.addEventListener('dragend', function (e) {
            this.classList.remove('drag');
            return false;
        }, false);
    };
});
app.directive('droppable', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            drop: '&',
            bin: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var el = element[0];
            el.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
                e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
                if (e.preventDefault)
                    e.preventDefault();
                this.classList.add('over');
                return false;
            }, false);
            el.addEventListener('dragenter', function (e) {
                this.classList.add('over');
                return false;
            }, false);
            el.addEventListener('dragleave', function (e) {
                this.classList.remove('over');
                return false;
            }, false);
            el.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
                if (e.stopPropagation)
                    e.stopPropagation();
                this.classList.remove('over');
                var binId = this.id;
                var item = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
                this.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" -- " + item.innerHTML));
                //this.appendChild(item);
                scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                    var fn = scope.drop();
                    if ('undefined' !== typeof fn) {
                        fn(item.id, binId);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }, false);
        }
    };
});
```

I create the draggable and droppable items using ng-repeat on field received from server as:(code snippet limited here because of complexity)

```
<button class="btn btn-danger elements bin" droppable drop="handleDrop" id="{{element.name}}">{{ element.name }}</button>
```

I need to remove the "droppable" from this bin "b", or at least disable it after I drop some item "i" onto this bin "b". Same goes for "draggable".

```
<th ng-repeat="field in tab.excelFields" class="btn btn-danger item" draggable style="display:table-cell;" id="{{field}}" value="{{field}}">{{field}}</th>
```

The number of elements in both can be very large, so I couldn't come up with a solution using ngIf.

Any clue how to disable/remove directives for certain elements after I have used those directives on these elements?